# How To add article without joomla classes

Tags: php, joomla, addition, article

I would like to add an article in joomla without using joomla classes.
I tried to insert a article data in the database in the table "content" but then I did not see the article. I discovered that the table "content" refers to the table "assets" but not how to treat.
I need to follow this approach in my php script I have to automate.

Comment: So you're trying to add an article to Joomla without using the admin backend or the Joomla API?

Comment: THe point of using a CMS is to use the cms classes and structure. An article in Joomla is created with the Joomla content api and that will handle the asset table as well as inserting it in a category and making sure its checked out/checked in category is correct as well as dealigwith FKs. If you want to add articles programatically you should write a cli script using the Joomla API.

Comment: Yes I know, I have a script that uses the working classes of Joomla. The problem with this method is that each invocation of the script I lose the session. Instead it needs to remain active to exhaust all records involved in the operation.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after several tests I recommend also using the classes of Joomla to create an article from your code. Inputting data directly to an article in the db you might run into some lack that affects the display of other items and categories.